# delete with alias and two conditions only delete one row

Tags: mysql, alias, delete-row

I am trying delete all relations like these

```
SELECT * 
  FROM wr_entidadUsuario a
 WHERE a.entidad_id IS NOT NULL
   AND a.usuario_id IN (117)
   AND a.entidad_id IN (330,429,425,427,428
                       ,308, 10,313,400,357
                       ,406,416,356, 46,314
                       ,104,326,327,328,361
                       ,351,360,399,282,310)
```

22 row(s) returned

but when i try to delete these rows only 1 is affected

```
DELETE a
  FROM wr_entidadUsuario a
 WHERE a.entidad_id IS NOT NULL
   AND a.usuario_id IN (117)
   AND a.entidad_id IN (330,429,425,427,428
                       ,308, 10,313,400,357
                       ,406,416,356, 46,314
                       ,104,326,327,328,361
                       ,351,360,399,282,310)
```

1 row(s) affected

what is the problem?

I am using mysql

Comment: i don´t understand what is happening, all is written correctly, the only difference is select delete

Comment: Could it be a suppressed error relating to some kind of FK constraint?

Comment: i don´t have FK, i only have a PK in entidad_id, usuario_id

Comment: if i delete only by one column the delete is well done

Comment: Sorry. I cannot replicate this behaviour.

Comment: i have dropped the PK and the delete has worked but i don´t understand what is the difference